# Error installing Pandas on Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using Python 3.6 on Windows 10. When I try to install Pandas, I get this error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1
```

Can anyone help me fix this please ?

Comment: Use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) or [Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) and then `conda install pandas` in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

```
step 1 :install pip 

step 2 : go to terminal and enter
         pip install pandas
```